# Use tags as variant in Shopify

Tags: html, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm trying to use the tags as a variant in shopify. So now every tag that has 'str.' in it shows up on the products pages is the product has the tag.

What my question is, how do I show all the tags that holds 'str.' in the same dropdown menu. Now it only show four different tags in separate dropdown menus. Any takers?

```
        {% for tag in product.tags %}
        {% if tag contains 'str.'%}
        
          <label for="Storrelse"> </label>
             <select name="str" id="Stoerrelse" form="{{product_form_id}}" name="properties[Størrelse]"/>
                <option value="{{tag}}"> {{tag}}</option>

             </select>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop inside the select

```
      <label for="Storrelse"> </label>
         <select name="str" id="Stoerrelse" form="{{product_form_id}}" name="properties[Størrelse]"/>
    {% for tag in product.tags %}
    {% if tag contains 'str.'%}
            <option value="{{tag}}"> {{tag}}</option>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
         </select>
```